# How Do I Fix My Social Sharing - Bad HTTP Response Code

Tags: facebook-opengraph, social-networking, sharing

For my website, https://sccparentsassociation.com/, I cannot share any articles / pages on facebook due to facebook not scraping my site.
When I try the debugger, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsccparentsassociation.com%2F, it gives me "URL returned a bad HTTP response code",  Response Code 418.

My site is moving slower than normal. I spent hours chatting with my hosting tech support and they swear it’s nothing on their end. I checked troubleshooting docs with All-In-One SEO and the page source data is all as it should be... Can anyone help please?

I've deactivated multiple plug-ins and even tried Yoast in lieu of All-In-One SEO.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely being caused by your SSL certificate! You should check if it really has been installed correctly and that the certificate chain is complete! For me the certificate CA file was implemented incorrectly. Some sites and browsers ignore this while others like Facebook are more restrictive. After fixing this, my HTTP status code changed immidiately from 418 to 206 and suddenly all OG values started to work on Facebook as well. Before all OG tags got ignored.